# Creating text without repetition

Tags: c#, optimization, algorithm

The basic idea is not to allow the same text and add +1 at the end.

Imagine that I have a datagrid (WPF) with names, and every time I click the add button, I will put a new name on the list automatically by running this method to ensure that no two names are alike.

My standard used: if there is repeated text, add to the end "(" + count + ")", similar to Windows Explorer.

Are there ways to make this using LINQ or Regex?

```
private void Test()
{
    var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t", "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t(8)", "t(9)", "t(10)" });
    Assert.IsTrue(result == "t(11)");
}

public static String CreateText(string newText, String[] texts)
{
    int addCount = 0;
    foreach (String text in texts)
    {
        if (text.IndexOf(newText) == 0)
        {
            if (text == newText && addCount == 0)
            {
                addCount = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (text.LastIndexOf('(') == newText.Length && text.LastIndexOf(')') == text.Length - 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var initial = text.LastIndexOf('(') + 1;
                        var size = text.LastIndexOf(')') - initial;
                        int count = Int16.Parse(text.Substring(initial, size));
                        if (addCount <= count)
                        {
                            addCount = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        addCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (addCount > 0)
    {
        newText += "(" + addCount + ")";
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Comment: It looks kind of under specified to me. What is the output of {"t(1)", "a(2)"}? {"t(t(1))", "T(42)"}? {"hello","world"}? Your test suggests you didn't clarify to yourself what are the requirements here.

Comment: @avip sorry, I will clarify the operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is shorter method with regex

```
    private static String CreateText(string textIdentifier, IEnumerable<string> texts)
    {
        const int defaultNumber = 1;

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(\s*(?<num>\d+)\s*\)");

        var numbers = 
            texts.Select(p => p.Trim()).Where(p => p.StartsWith(textIdentifier))
            .Select(str => { var m = regex.Match(str); return m.Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["num"].Value) + 1 : defaultNumber; });

        int max = numbers.Any() ? numbers.Max() : 0;

        return max == 0 ? textIdentifier : string.Format("{0}({1})", textIdentifier, max);
    }
```

+1 to @dreza for tests ;)

Answer (score 3):

There might be one problem with @Danil code.  Although it passes the unit test that was provided what if the array contained values of `"t", "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t(8)", "t(9)", "test(10)"`

In this case I would think you would want the return value to be `t(10)`.  Maybe the above scenerio is not possible, but if it is, here is a revision to @Danil code which would handle it.

```
private static String CreateText(string textIdentifier, IEnumerable<string> texts)
{
    const int defaultNumber = 0;

    Regex regex = new Regex("^" + textIdentifier + @"\(\s*(?<num>\d+)\s*\)");

    var max = 
        texts.Select(p => p.Trim())
        .Select(str => { var m = regex.Match(str); return m.Success ? int.Parse(m.Groups["num"].Value) + 1 : defaultNumber; })
        .Max();

    return max == 0 ? textIdentifier : string.Format("{0}({1})", textIdentifier, max);
}
```

Comment: Yep, you are right. I've missed it.

Comment: worked well in tests. but looking now, this code does not meet one of the requirements. it still lets texts exactly alike.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way.  Not fully Linq but using a little bit in the for loop.  Also passes a few more unit tests than your original.

**[EDIT]**:  After re-reading your question and some comments by other reviewers I added a few more unit tests and low and behold my original answer broke.  So I've re-worked it and now made it even more complicated :) but passes the new unit tests I put in 10,11 and 12.

Whether your code needs to pass thoses tests or not though I'll leave that for you to decide.

As for optimization.  I haven't profiled it so can't comment there.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t", "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t(8)", "t(9)", "t(10)" });
        Assert.IsTrue(result == "t(11)");
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(1)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t", "t(4)", "t(2)", "z(3)", "t (45)", "t5)", "t(10)", "t(12)", "t( 89 ),ttt, t, t(23), t(8, t(we", "t( 89 )", "t(23)", "t(8", "t(we" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(90)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test3()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { });
        Assert.IsTrue(result == "t");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test4()
    {
        var result = CreateText("z", new string[] { "t(1)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("z", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test5()
    {
        var result = CreateText("z", new string[] { "t(-1)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("z", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test6()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "    t(0)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(1)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test7()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "    t(9)     " });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(10)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test8()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t(8)", "t(9)", "test(10)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(10)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test9()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t(8)", "t (9)", "test(10)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(10)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test10()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t(5)", "t(6)", "t(7)", "t t(8)", "t (9)", "test(10)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(10)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test11()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t((((24)", "ttt(22)", "t(7)", "t t(8)", "t (9)", "t(1)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(10)", result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test12()
    {
        var result = CreateText("t", new string[] { "t(1)", "t(2)", "t(3)", "t(4)", "t((((24)", "ttt(22)", "t(29)) ))", "t t(8)", "t (9)", "t(1)" });
        Assert.AreEqual("t(30)", result);
    }

    private static String CreateText(string textIdentifier, IEnumerable<string> texts)
    {
        const char startDeliminator = '(';
        const char endDeliminator = ')';

        int nextCount = 0;

        foreach (String text in texts.Select(p => p.Trim()).Where(p => p.StartsWith(textIdentifier)))
        {
            short addCount = 0;

            var startDelminatorIndex = text.LastIndexOf(startDeliminator);

            // there must be at least one start deliminator
            if (startDelminatorIndex >= 0)
            {
                var endDeliminatorIndex = text.IndexOf(endDeliminator, startDelminatorIndex);
                var textName = text.Substring(0, startDelminatorIndex).Trim();

                if (textName.Equals(textIdentifier, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (endDeliminatorIndex > startDelminatorIndex)
                    {
                        startDelminatorIndex++; // get past the (
                        var size = endDeliminatorIndex - startDelminatorIndex;
                        Int16.TryParse(text.Substring(startDelminatorIndex, size).Trim(), out addCount);
                    }
                }
            }

            nextCount = Math.Max(nextCount, addCount + 1);
        }

        return nextCount == 0 ? textIdentifier : string.Format("{0}({1})", textIdentifier, nextCount);
    }
```

Comment: good idea to use the linq before the loop, although I think that horrible "p.Trim()"

Comment: Yeah, unless you don't need to worry about whitespace i.e. assume it's already trimmed you could remove it.  However without Test7 and Test6 don't pass.